# form_for submit button not working on Rails 5, it freezes up when submitting

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a simple CRUD Blog app for video games where users can write reviews for video games they've played.

In my *games/new.html.erb*,

I'm trying to create a new game and an associated review through nested forms. Earlier it was working, but now since I've added bootstrap styling and partials to my code, **the submit button isn't working anymore, it freezes up when I try to submit my form:**

```
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Add Game and/or Review!" data-disable-with="Add Game and/or Review!" disabled="">
```

Idk why this is happening but since the only thing I've tried to change since testing out this feature is basic bootstrap and styling, I suspect that I'm missing a closing HTML tag somewhere and that is causing my partials rendering to error.

For full clarity, this is my repo on github: https://github.com/jchu4483/Rails-Assessment-/tree/bootstrap_styling

Thanks, and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try doing this <%= f.submit "Add Game and/or Review!", disabled: false %> in your games/new.html.erb

Comment: Hm, that didn't work.

Comment: Still having trouble with this.